How to get Formset data in clean method and validate it - Django
I am using Formset as a field in a form. I am unable to get the Formset data in clean method.
sharing code here.
Forms.py
  class MyForm(forms.Form):
      my_field = forms.CharField()

  MyFormSet = formset_factory(MyForm, extra=2)

  class MainForm(forms.Form):
      main_field = forms.CharField()
      my_formset = MyFormSet()
      def clean(self):
          cleaned_data = super().clean()
          my_formset = cleaned_data.get('my_formset')
          print(my_formset,"my_formset") 

my_formset is getting printed as "None", even if i give data to the fields.
Html:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Main Form</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Main Form</h1>
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <label for="id_main_field">Main Field:</label>
    {{ main_form.main_field }}
    
    <h2>Formset Fields</h2>
    {{ main_form.my_formset.management_form }}
    {% for form in main_form.my_formset %}
        <div>
            {{ form.my_field.label_tag }}
            {{ form.my_field }}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>

How can i get the Formset data in clean method.

You would want to handle this with utilizing two forms. One formset_form and one main_form. Handle two separate forms in your view but put them in one 'form'-html-tag in your template.
